# How can I get the alternates of SAPI speech recognization result

Tags: sapi

On windows7 platform I can use System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine to convert voice to text.By SpeechRecognitionEngine when the SpeechRecognized event triggered I can get some alternate words,and I can show these word to users for choise.

```
void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.SpeechRecognized != null)
    {
       this.SpeechRecognized(this, new RecognizedResultEventArgs
            {
                Text = e.Result.Text,
                Alternates = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(e.Result.Alternates.Select(p => p.Text).ToList())
            });
    }
}
```

By the way,when I initialise SpeechRecognitionEngine instance,I want to load some  specifical word instead of use "DictationGrammar".

My program need to runing on xp platform sometimes.So I want to implament a specific vertion to run on xp operating system by use sapi5.1.

I have readed a portion of sapi 5.1 document,then I get that:in sapi5.1,I can use "command and control" way to do that. but the "Result.Alternates()" method can not be used when I use "command and control".So,how can I achieve the same effect of SpeechRecognitionEngine ?

I tried the following code and there is an com Eception:

```
public void RecoContext_Recognition(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, SpeechRecognitionType RecognitionType, ISpeechRecoResult Result)
    {
        ISpeechPhraseProperty oItem;

        oItem = Result.PhraseInfo.Properties.Item(0);

        if ((System.Decimal)Result.PhraseInfo.GrammarId == grammarId)
        {
            if (this.SpeechRecognized != null)
            {
                RecognizedResultEventArgs e = new RecognizedResultEventArgs();
                e.Text = oItem.Name;

                // The following code throws an exception
                ISpeechPhraseAlternates alternates = Result.Alternates(10);
                List<string> s = new List<string>();
                foreach (ISpeechPhraseAlternate item in alternates)
                {
                    s.Add(item.RecoResult.PhraseInfo.Properties.Item(0).Name);
                }
                e.Alternates = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(s);

                this.SpeechRecognized(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to get the alternates by use sapi by way of COM?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In SAPI (any version), command and control grammars don't have alternates.  Only dictation grammars have alternates.

Comment: Thank you.However,I can not understand the System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine class can set words range to recgnize and has alternates.

Comment: Because this was added in Sapi 5.3.  But even under Sapi 5.3, while you can *ask* for alternates, you will only get the original reco.